# What is lower image?

Tags: vectors, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I need to learn some basics from convex vector optimization and this term (lower image) I somehow cannot grasp... here is context:

$ \max f(x) \qquad (\text{ with respect to the} \leq_K)\qquad (P)\\
\text{s.t.} \;\; g(x)\leq 0.$

$\cdot$ $\chi = \{x \in X: g(x)\leq 0 \}$ is convex

$\cdot$ $LI= \text{cl}(f(\chi)-K)$ is called **lower image** of $(P)$

($K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^q $ is solid, pointed, polyhedral convex ordering cone, $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^q $ is $K$-concave, $g:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is $\mathbb{R}^m _+$-convex)

Comment: Use <dollarsign>latex code<dollarsign> to write in latex on this forum. Here's a great resource for looking up latex code. You can look up symbols by drawing them in the box. http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: what is "this term" that you cannot grasp?  Your question makes no sense, otherwise.  Did you intend to add the URL to an image of the "term"?

Comment: I know how to write latex code, I just didn't know how to plug it into the text of my queston on this webpage.
By "this term" I refer to the term mentioned in the title i.e. "lower image".

Comment: Perhaps you were reading a passage in a text, or notes, where there was a reference to "lower image" (meaning, an image placed below the passage.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In optimization the set $\chi$ is called the *feasible set*. Those are the points among which we are searching the optimal ones.

In general, if $A$ is a set contained in the domain of a function $f$, then $f(A)$ is defined to be $$f(A) = \{f(x):\ x\in A\}$$

The set $f(A)$ is called *the image of $A$ by applying $f$*.

The next thing that is relevant is the subtraction $A - B$ of two sets of vectors. $$A-B = \{x -y:\ x\in A\text{ and }y\in B\}$$

In your case $K$ is an ordering cone. You need to grok what happens to a set $A$ when you subtract the cone $K$. Start by looking at the case of one point $A=\{p\}$. In that case $A-K = -K + A$ looks like placing the code with the vertex at $p$ but pointing in the opposite direction as $K$, i.e. downwards.

For a general $A$, $A-K$ would look like a union of copies of $K$ starting at every point of $A$ and pointing in the opposite direction as $K$; like $A$ casting a shadow downwards.

In your case $A$ would be $F(\chi)$. So, it is like the downward shadow of the image of $\chi$ by $f$. I guess that is why they are calling it *lower image*.

Try simple examples:

1. $f$ constant. Then $f(\chi)$ is one point.
2. $f$ being linear, sending $\chi$ into a line.

Comment: Thx, sounds understandable.